# Which has a greater dipole: chloroform (CHCl3) or trichlorofluoromethane (CCl3F)?

Tags: organic-chemistry, dipole

Does chloroform have a greater dipole because the $\ce{C-H}$ dipole is weaker than $\ce{C-Cl}$ dipole thereby making the overall net dipole greater in chloroform, as opposed to trichlorofluoromethane where the $\ce{C-F}$ bond dipole being more similar to the $\ce{C-Cl}$ dipole makes the molecule more stable with a smaller net dipole?

Comment: C-H and C-F dipoles are in opposite directions; which of them has greater absolute value is not immediately obvious.

Answer (score 4):

Imagine a $\ce{CHCl3}$ molecule and a $\ce{CFCl3}$ molecule fixed with the carbon atom of each molecule at the origin of a three-dimensional coordinate system. Select the two coordinate systems such that the hydrogen atom of the $\ce{CHCl3}$ molecule and the fluorine atom of the $\ce{CFCl3}$ molecule both lie on the $z$-axis above the origin, and let $u_z$ be the $z$ unit vector. If the four single covalent bonds of each molecule are symmetrical (here, tetrahedral), then it follows that the net vector sum of any four vectors that are equal in magnitude and are directed in the four directions from the origin to each non-carbon atom will be the zero vector. In both molecules, the net vector dipole moment arising from the three $\ce{C-Cl}$ bonds will equal the dipole moment of a single $\ce{C-Cl}$ bond with the chlorine atom in the direction of $-u_z$ from the carbon atom.

Assuming *arguendo* that the dipole moment of each bond is proportional to the difference in electronegativity of the two atoms between which that bond lies (on the Pauling Electronegativity Scale, hydrogen rates a $2.1$, carbon rates a $2.5$, chlorine rates a $3.0$, and fluorine rates a $4.0$), then to find the dipole moment of the $\ce{CHCl3}$ molecule, we add the vector dipole moment of the $\ce{C-H}$ bond ($[(2.1 - 2.5) \cdot u_z]$, or $-0.4 u_z$) to the vector dipole moment of the $\ce{C-Cl}$ bond ($[(3.0 - 2.5) \cdot (-u_z)]$, or $-0.5 u_z$), obtaining $[(-0.4 u_z) + (-0.5 u_z)]$ or $-0.9 u_z$.

To find the dipole moment of the $\ce{CFCl3}$ molecule, we add the vector dipole moment of the $\ce{C-F}$ bond ($[(4.0 - 2.5) \cdot u_z]$, or $1.5 u_z$) to the vector dipole moment of the $\ce{C-Cl}$ bond ($[(3.0 - 2.5) \cdot (-u_z)]$, or $-0.5 u_z$), obtaining $[(1.5 u_z) + (-0.5 u_z)]$ or $1.0 u_z$.

One might thus conclude that the dipole moment of $\ce{CFCl3}$ might be some ten percent larger in magnitude (as proportional to 1.0) than is that of $\ce{CHCl3}$ (as proportional to 0.9).

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry SE! Please enclose chemical compounds in `$\ce{ }$` and normal latex in `$ $`for the latex formatting to take effect

Answer (score 2):

$\ce{C-Cl}$ in $\ce{CHCl3}$ all lies in same direction and hence net vector sum is downwards, which makes it's dipole moment greater, while in $\ce{CFCl3}$ three $\ce{C-Cl}$ bonds are in same direction while one $\ce{C-F}$ lies in opposite direction to them thus while adding dipoles as vectors we need to subtract dipole of $\ce{C-F}$ from dipole of three $\ce{C-Cl}$ thus reducing net dipole moment.

Hence dipole moment of $\ce{CHCl3}$ is greater than $\ce{CFCl3}$ .

Comment: It would be nice to amend this with some data, like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chloroform_(data_page) and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trichlorofluoromethane_(data_page) (for starters)